# Mostrar informação sem atualizar página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou criando um projeto em que eu terei "duas interfaces", uma usada pelo celular, e outra usada em um computador, na do celular eu vou ter a API do YouTube, usando `list`, com JavaScript.

O cliente que estiver usando, vai pesquisar um vídeo do seu interesse e poderá pré-vizualizar o mesmo, e eventualmente selecioná-lo, quando selecioná-lo, a ID do vídeo será salva em um banco de dados, assim como também seu nome (haverá uma tela de login antes), eu preciso que a outra interface mostre esses vídeos, mas terei que receber essas informações do banco e não atualizar a página, e também vou fazer um botão de marcar um vídeo como já reproduzido...

Preciso de ajuda nessa parte de exibir os novos vídeos e remover os que já foram marcados como tocados.

Também me pergunto se PHP e JS seria o mais indicado para esse tipo de projeto, com "duas interfaces" (se esse tipo de projeto tiver um nome específico, por favor me digam), sei que existem WEB SOCKETS, mas ainda não estudei a fundo sobre isso.

Comment: Oi, Rodrigo, tomei a liberdade de eliminar certas coisas da sua pergunta que distraiam do objetivo principal. Mesmo assim, ainda está muito amplo... O site aqui é pra perguntas o mais objetivas possíveis pra ter a resposta o mais exata possível. Não tem problema nenhum você perguntar durante toda a execução do projeto, mas tem que ir pedaço a pedaço. E, claro, só deve perguntar quando realmente já pesquisou, bateu cabeça e não resolveu. E, bem-vindo ao SOpt :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boa noite!

Você parece ser um cara inteligente, postou e já respondeu a própria dúvida.

O seu problema pode e deve ser resolvido utilizando websockets. Essa é a tecnologia mais simples para esse tipo de problema.

Se procura por algum produto bom, eu recomendo e utilizo o [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/).

Estude a tecnologia que será um tempo muito bem investido.

Abrs!

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas :)
Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre... 
Eu já dei uma olhada no firebase também, mas não a fundo. 
Abraço, 
Um ótimo dia.